# Why do the last element footer exceed the parent height?

Tags: html, css

Why the footer element exceeds the height of its parent wrapper when it should have been a fraction of the height of its parent wrapper.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Slicing</title>

<style type="text/css">
html,body{  
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

    }
div#wrapper{    
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        line-height:normal;
        border:#C00 thick groove;
        background-color:#FF3;
    }

div#wrapper div#header{
        width:100%;
        height:30%;
        border:#F00 medium double;

    }


div#wrapper div#body{
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
        border:#F00 medium double;

    }

div#wrapper div#footer{
        width:100%;
        height:20%;
        border:#F00 medium double;

    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="hlogo">

        </div>
        <div id="hdesign">

        </div>
        <div id="hTestimonial">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `border`s are combining together to make it too high.

`border`s are not considered part of `height`. See [the box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-dimensions).

Each of your `border`s is around `3px`, and it's on both the top and bottom, so that's `6px`.

You have the same `border` on three relevant elements, so that's where the ~`18px` of "extra height" is coming from.

Your page: http://jsbin.com/epodu5
Exact same but with `border`s removed and different `background-color`s: http://jsbin.com/epodu5/2

If you only care about modern browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing), the easiest way to fix it is to use CSS3's [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing):

Like this: http://jsbin.com/epodu5/3

> border-box
>
> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden` for parent